# Recursively padding 0's in names of files and folders

Tags: linux, bash, rename, zsh, pad

I have a folder containing video lectures on some particular topic. It is structured like this:

```
.
├── 1_fol
│   ├── 1_file.mp4
│   ├── 2_file.mp4
│   └── 3_file.mp4
└── 2_fol
    ├── 10_file.mp4
    ├── 4_file.mp4
    ├── 5_file.mp4
    ├── 6_file.mp4
    ├── 7_file.mp4
    ├── 8_file.mp4
    └── 9_file.mp4
```

I want to change this structure into

```
.
├── 001_fol
│   ├── 001_file.mp4
│   ├── 002_file.mp4
│   └── 003_file.mp4
└── 002_fol
    ├── 004_file.mp4
    ├── 005_file.mp4
    ├── 006_file.mp4
    ├── 007_file.mp4
    ├── 008_file.mp4
    ├── 009_file.mp4
    └── 010_file.mp4
```

This helps, because you can then use `find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/.*\.\(mp3\|mp4\)" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 vlc` to open the whole playlist. I came up with a script to pad 0's, but it's quite **lengthy** and **slow**:

```
find . -depth -exec rename -v 's/(.*)\/([0-9]$)/$1\/00$2/;
      s/(.*)\/([0-9]{2}$)/$1\/0$2/;
      s/(.*)\/([0-9][^0-9][^\/]*$)/$1\/00$2/;
      s/(.*)\/([0-9]{2}[^0-9][^\/]*$)/$1\/0$2/' '{}' ';'
```

Can this be optimized further?

**Edit**
Actually, the execution became quite fast after the ';' was changed to '+'. But the set of regex(es) still looks quite ugly.

Comment: Rename is the right command to use. If there are non-mp4 files in there you could let find select them first with `-name`. It may be easier to rename all the files to have 3 leading zeros then rename back the ones with 4 or 5 digits.

Comment: Are you reprocessing each file too many times. Find finds each file in turn, so execs 3 times in the first folder, but rename works on all files in the folder again and again?

Comment: I think a '+' would be better instead of ';' at the end.. what changes do you suggest @GemTaylor? why '3' times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rename` is a perl tool and allows you to use any perl expressions. The following perl expression searches for the last component of a path (for instance `c` in `a/b/c`) and pads its leading number (if existing) to three digits.

```
s/(^|\/)\K(\d+)(?=[^\/]*$)/sprintf "%03d",$2/e
```

**Example:**

- `1_fol/23_file.mp4` becomes `1_fol/023_file.mp4`
- `1_fol` becomes `001_fol`
- `1_2/3_4.mp4` becomes `1_2/003_4.mp4`
- `1_2` becomes `001_2`

Use above perl expression in your `find` command for `bash`✱ ...

```
find -depth -exec rename 's/(^|\/)\K(\d+)(?=[^\/]*$)/sprintf "%03d",$2/ge' {} +
```

... or the extended globstar features in `zsh`. On my system globs were faster than `find`.

```
rename 's/(^|\/)\K(\d+)(?=[^\/]*$)/sprintf "%03d",$2/ge' **/*(On)
```

`**/*` recursively lists all files and directories and `(On)` reverses the order similar to `-depth`.

✱ For `bash` you still could use `**/*` with `shopt -s globstar` but reversing the order of the matched files is not so easy, so `find` is simpler and probably faster.

Comment: This is perfect! But, `shopt` is not available in `zsh`. Is there any alternative for `zsh`?

Comment: I updated my answer. In this case globstars do not work as I thought because of the directory creation problem. Normal globs should be sufficient in your case. Anyway: `zsh` does support globstars. I think they should be enabled by default. Simply omit the `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: find -depth is like depth-first search, and for each search result I modified contents after the last '/'. Hence all the files in a directory have already been renamed before renaming the folder.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed you renamed `1_fol/1_file.mp4` to `001_fol/001_file.mp4` in one step. Pretty neat. I incorporated your approach into my answer.